# How does a large file, like a 20gb game, fit into memory?

Tags: performance, memory, storage, ram

How does a large file, say a 20GB game, fit into memory? I am keeping myself up just thinking about this and I just don't understand it.

Comment: Ever since virtual memory became commonplace, physical ram just serves as another layer of caching between the disk and the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. It remains on disk and is read in as needed. Windows has a special API for doing this that makes it completely transparent to the programmer - google MemoryMappedFile that describes how to open a file that is too large to hold in RAM.

Games though, may use different techniques, reading in parts of the file that are needed at any given time so for example, all levels might be held in a single file, but the game will open the filew, seek to the right place, and read the data from the file as the player enters a new level.

Comment: Awesome, you have explained it very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is on the disk. Game reads chunks of it that needed in the meantime.